# How can I find whether a file is infected by virus using VirusTotal.NET library in C#?

Tags: c#, virus-scanning

I am currently using VirusTotal.NET nuget package in my C# MVC project to scan uploaded files. I am using the same example given here https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotal.NET

```
VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("YOUR API KEY HERE");

//Use HTTPS instead of HTTP
virusTotal.UseTLS = true;

//Create the EICAR test virus. See http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html
byte[] eicar = 
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*");

//Check if the file has been scanned before.
FileReport report = await virusTotal.GetFileReportAsync(eicar);

Console.WriteLine("Seen before: " + (report.ResponseCode == FileReportResponseCode.Present ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

I am loading the byte array of the uploaded file to `eicar` variable in the above code. According to the given example, it will provide the file is scanned before or not. But what I actually need is whether the file is infected or not. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Checking out the [UrlReport](https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotal.Net/blob/48470e148b28c9ebad8fcaf8e0578faa24c81ef8/VirusTotal.NET/Results/UrlReport.cs) class, the report you get back has a lot more info than just the response code in their code sample. There are 3 fields that look interesting:

```
/// <summary>
/// How many engines flagged this resource.
/// </summary>
public int Positives { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// The scan results from each engine.
/// </summary>
public Dictionary<string, UrlScanEngine> Scans { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// How many engines scanned this resource.
/// </summary>
public int Total { get; set; }
```

This may give you the results you're looking for. VirusTotal actually returns results for multiple scan engines, some of which might detect a virus and some which might not.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{report.Positives} out of {report.Total} scan engines detected a virus.");
```

You could do anything you want with that data, like calculate the percentage:

```
var result = 100m * report.Positives / report.Total;
Console.WriteLine($"{result}% of scan engines detected a virus.");
```

Or just treat a majority of positive scan engine results as an overall positive result:

```
var result = Math.Round(report.Positives / Convert.ToDecimal(report.Total));
Console.WriteLine($"Virus {(result == 0 ? "not detected": "detected")});
```

Comment: I think the threshold should be way below 50%.  It's unlikely for even 10% of engines to see a false positive on the same file.